# What's the significance of Tangut?

Tags: topolect, mainland-china

With the preparation of the Tangut script for Unicode there seems to be extra added attention on the language, recently.

Tangut being a dead, sinitic language with a script all of its own.

What is the significance of the Tangut language?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the relation between Tangut and Chinese is too weak to be on-topic.

Comment: I brought this up on meta [Is Tangut ("an ancient northeastern Tibeto-Burman language") on-topic?](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1845)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No other significance than being a historical language and script of interest to academia. As such, it has a given role in Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Tangut language is believe to be close to Tibetan, while the writing system of it was a mimic of Chinese characters.

Tangut people are believed to be massacred by Mongolian invaders and the rest of them, if there is any, are believed to conceal their national identity and eventually become a part of other ethnic groups.

The importance of Tangut language is purely of academia, as it's a dead language.